# how to end if and move to other line

Tags: java

My problems starts when I want to see the condition and then move to another line but there is no "goto" in java so I have no clue how to move from inside of this if and go to the next line one ther hand when I put return after that it doesn't run the code .... 
I would aprieciate I f you guys help me with this problem... 
source code is here :::

```
  //package CaloriesCalculator
 import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
// @SuppressWarnings("null")
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Initiate a new Scanner
    // here I have tried to use scanner
    boolean run = true;
    while(run){
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner userInputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.print("\nIf you are Male Press 1, If you are Female Press 2 ");

            int G = userInputScanner.nextInt();

            if(G == 1)

                {
                            System.out.print("Please Enter your Weight.."); 
                            int W = userInputScanner.nextInt();

                            if((W <300) && (W > 1)) {//error message


                                //      my problems start here !! I need to have the next input here but it doesn't work



                            }
                            System.out.print("Please Enter your Weight.."); 
                            W= userInputScanner.nextInt();
                            return;
                            //  int m;
                            System.out.print("Please Enter your Height");
                            int H = userInputScanner.nextInt();
                                System.out.print("Please Enter your Age.."); 
                                int A = userInputScanner.nextInt();

                                double BMR = 10*W + 6.25*H - 5*A +5 ;

                                    if( BMR > 0)    {System.out.print(" Your body needs the amount of calories : "+ BMR );}

                                        else { System.out.print("Do you know you are a mess ?  " );}





                            //int H = userInputScanner.nextInt();



                            //  else {System.out.print("Please Enter valid weight");}   
                }

            else if(G == 2)

                {

                        System.out.print("Please Enter your Weight.."); 
                        int W = userInputScanner.nextInt();

                        System.out.print("Please Enter your Height"); 
                        int H = userInputScanner.nextInt();

                        System.out.print("Please Enter your Age.."); 
                        int A = userInputScanner.nextInt();

                        double BMR = 10*W + 6.25*H - 5*A -161 ;


                                if(BMR > 0)
                                    {
                                        System.out.print(" Your body needs the amount of calories : "+ BMR );
                                    }

                                else
                                    {
                                        System.out.print("Do you know you are a mess ?  " );

                                    }


        }
            else
            {
                System.out.print(" Please put the right number or don't use program " );
            }
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`nextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()) method [doesn't read the whole line (with carriage return and line feed)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7056782/3735079), thus when you reread the `nextInt()` you get an empty string, that's why your if doesn't execute the code in it.

You have to:

1. First use `nextLine()` to read the entire line.
2. Use `Integer.parseInt()` method to validate the integer input.

In other words:

```
Scanner userInputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String s = userInputScanner.nextLine();

try{
    Integer.parseInt(s);
}
catch(NumberFormatException ex){
    System.out.println("Its not a valid Integer");
}
```

Otherwise you can do a `nextInt()` and then a `nextLine()` to consume the `\n`:

```
int number = input.nextInt();
input.nextLine(); // This line you have to add (It consumes the \n character)
```

Comment: tnx for the help but i couldn't make it work.. I am too beginner to JAVa to understand this code ... I couldn't find the right place for it or even if I did i got many other errors... :(

Comment: That's a pity! Try your exact same code, just add the line `userInputScanner.nextLine()` after `int G = userInputScanner.nextInt();` and `int W = userInputScanner.nextInt();` (or everytime you are using `nextInt()`)